# Code to refresh this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, minecraft

I am not very good with javascript or anything. What can I add to make this minecraft server query update every 10 seconds? At the moment it is a bit slow so it takes awhile to recognise players that are leaving or joining. Also how can I make this script show a list of player names that are currently in-game on each server?

CODE:

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></link>

<style type="text/css">



/*Bootstrap styles*/

@-webkit-keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
from {
background-position: 40px 0;
}
to {
background-position: 0 0;
}
}
@keyframes progress-bar-stripes {
from {
background-position: 40px 0;
}
to {
background-position: 0 0;
}
}
.progress {
overflow: hidden;
height: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #333;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.progress-bar {
float: left;
width: 0%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
background-color: #428bca;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
-webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
transition: width 0.6s ease;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress.active .progress-bar {
-webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}
.progress-bar-success {
background-color: #5cb85c;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-success {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-bar-info {
background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-info {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-bar-warning {
background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-warning {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress-bar-danger {
background-color: #d9534f;
}
.progress-striped .progress-bar-danger {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}

.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em .6em .3em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  border-radius: .25em;
}
.label[href]:hover,
.label[href]:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.label:empty {
  display: none;
}
.btn .label {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
}

.label-default {
background-color: #999999;
}
.label-default[href]:hover,
.label-default[href]:focus {
background-color: #808080;
}
.label-primary {
background-color: #428bca;
}
.label-primary[href]:hover,
.label-primary[href]:focus {
background-color: #3071a9;
}
.label-success {
background-color: #5cb85c;
}
.label-success[href]:hover,
.label-success[href]:focus {
background-color: #449d44;
}
.label-info {
background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.label-info[href]:hover,
.label-info[href]:focus {
background-color: #31b0d5;
}
.label-warning {
background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.label-warning[href]:hover,
.label-warning[href]:focus {
background-color: #ec971f;
}
.label-danger {
background-color: #d9534f;
}
.label-danger[href]:hover,
.label-danger[href]:focus {
background-color: #c9302c;
}

/*End Bootstrap styles*/




/*Our labels for the online/offline stats*/

.serverdata .label{
float:right;

}

/*The container for all of the data*/

.servercontainer{
width:250px;
background-color:#555;
overflow:hidden;
color:white;

}

/*Main title*/

.servercontainer h1{
margin-bottom:15px;
color:white !important;
background-color:black;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
font-size:16px;
}

/*Padding for all of our server data, so they don't touch sides of container*/

.serverdata{
padding:6px;

}

/*Style for our loading text*/

.loading{
font-size:14px;
color:white;
padding:20px;
}

/*Each Server Title*/

.serverdata h2{
margin-bottom:10px;
color:white;
font-size:16px !important;
}

/*The text that displays player counts in progress bar*/

.progress h4{
    position:absolute
        
}

/*Hide running total, used for keeping player total without reset*/

.runningtotal{
display:none;
}

/*visible player total*/

.total-players{
padding:5px;
color:white;
background-color:#222;
}


.servercontainer i{
color:white;
}

</style>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
/*globals MinecraftAPI: true */
 
(function (servers) {
    'use strict';
 
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        script = document.createElement('script'),
        currentServer = 0,
        totalPlayers = [],
        allDone,
        buildServerStatusContainer,
        loadServerStatus,
        stringifyServer,
        buildStatusObject,
        buildOfflineStatusObject,
        buildErrorStatusObject;
 
    allDone = function (items, fn, done) {
        var completed = 0,
            len = items.length,
            i,
            callback;
 
        if (len === 0) {
            return done();
        }
 
        callback = function () {
            completed += 1;
 
            if (completed === len) {
                done();
            }
        };
 
        for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
            fn(items[i], callback);
        }
    };
 
    stringifyServer = function (server) {
        return server.name;
    };
 
    buildServerStatusContainer = function (server, index) {
        var serverData,
            loading,
            loadingtext,
            playerhead;
 
        serverData = document.createElement('div');
        serverData.classList.add('serverdata', 'server-' + currentServer);
 
        loading = document.createElement('i');
        loading.classList.add('fa', 'fa-spinner', 'fa-spin');
        loading.classList.add('loading-server', 'server-loading-' + currentServer);
 
        playerhead = document.createElement('div');
        playerhead.classList.add('playerhead', 'server-playerhead-' + currentServer);
 
        loadingtext = document.createElement('span');
        loadingtext.innerHTML = ' Loading...';

        serverData.appendChild(loading);
        serverData.appendChild(loadingtext);
        serverData.appendChild(playerhead);
 
        document.querySelector('.servercontainer').appendChild(serverData);
 
        servers[index].id = currentServer;
        currentServer += 1;
    };
 
    buildErrorStatusObject = function (server, status) {
        var container,
            ip,
            online;
 
        container = document.createElement('div');
 
        ip = document.createElement('h2');
        ip.innerHTML = stringifyServer(server);
 
        online = document.createElement('span');
        online.classList.add('label', 'label-danger');
        online.innerHTML = 'Error!';
        online.style.display = 'block';
 
        container.appendChild(ip);
        ip.appendChild(online);
 
        document.querySelector('.servercontainer .server-' + server.id).innerHTML = '';
        document.querySelector('.servercontainer .server-' + server.id).appendChild(container);
    };
 
    buildOfflineStatusObject = function (server, status) {
        var container,
            ip,
            online;
 
        container = document.createElement('div');
 
        ip = document.createElement('h2');
        ip.innerHTML = stringifyServer(server);
 
        online = document.createElement('span');
        online.classList.add('label', 'label-warning');
        online.innerHTML = 'Offline';
        online.style.display = 'block';
 
        container.appendChild(ip);
        ip.appendChild(online);
 
        document.querySelector('.servercontainer .server-' + server.id).innerHTML = '';
        document.querySelector('.servercontainer .server-' + server.id).appendChild(container);
    };
 
    buildStatusObject = function (server, status, lobby) {
        var item = document.querySelector('.servercontainer .server-' + server.id),
            progresswidth,
            container,
            ip,
            online,
            progress,
            progressbar,
            players;
 
        progresswidth = Math.floor((status.players.now / (lobby === undefined ? status.players.max : lobby)) * 100) + '%';
 
        container = document.createElement('div');
 
        ip = document.createElement('h2');
        ip.innerHTML = stringifyServer(server);
 
        online = document.createElement('span');
        online.classList.add('label', 'label-success');
        online.innerHTML = 'Online';
        online.style.display = 'block';
        online.style.marginBottom = '5px';
 
        progress = document.createElement('div');
        progress.classList.add('progress','progress-striped','active');
 
        progressbar = document.createElement('div');
        progressbar.classList.add('progress-bar', 'progress-bar-success');
        progressbar.style.width = progresswidth;
 
        progress.appendChild(progressbar);
 
        players = document.createElement('h4');
        players.innerHTML = status.players.now + ' / ' + (lobby === undefined ? status.players.max : lobby) + ' Players Online';
 
        container.appendChild(ip);
        ip.appendChild(online);
        container.appendChild(progress);
        progress.appendChild(players);
 
        item.innerHTML = '';
        item.appendChild(container);
 
        totalPlayers.push(status.players.now);
    };
 
    loadServerStatus = function (server, done) {
        MinecraftAPI.getServerStatus(server.ip, {
            port: server.port
        }, function (err, status) {
            if (err) {
                buildErrorStatusObject(server, status);
                done();
                return;
            }
 
            if (!status.online) {
                buildOfflineStatusObject(server, status);
                done();
                return;
            }
 
            if (status.players.max === 1) {
                buildStatusObject(server, status, server.lobby);
                done();
                return;
            }
 
            buildStatusObject(server, status);
 
            done();
        });
    };
 
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
        servers.forEach(buildServerStatusContainer);
 
        var totalplayers = document.createElement('h2');
        totalplayers.classList.add('total-players');
 
        document.querySelector('.servercontainer').appendChild(totalplayers);
 
        setInterval(function () {
            totalPlayers = [];
            allDone(servers, loadServerStatus, function () {
                document.querySelector('.total-players').innerHTML = totalPlayers.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) + ' Total Players';
            });
        }, 1000);
 
        allDone(servers, loadServerStatus, function () {
            document.querySelector('.total-players').innerHTML = totalPlayers.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) + ' Total Players';
        });
    });
 
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//mcapi.us/scripts/minecraft.min.js';
 
    head.appendChild(script);
}([{
    ip: '46.105.88.222',
    port: 25565,
    name: 'Promeion'
},{
    ip: '46.105.88.222',
    port: 25570,
    name: 'Hub',
    lobby: 252
}]));
});
</script>

<div class="servercontainer">
<h1>Promeion Network</h1>

</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, read about [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Examples](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

to let it run every 10 seconds put the script in a function and give it a name. Then you could use setTimeout() and wait a while. Put the setTimeout at the end of the function and call the function again from inside itself.

How to display players is more specific to the script you have there. Perhaps there is some documentation where you have it from?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the following bit of code, 1000 stands for 1 second interval of checking players amount. Try to modify it, and see if it changes anything.

```
setInterval(function () {
        totalPlayers = [];
        allDone(servers, loadServerStatus, function () {
            document.querySelector('.total-players').innerHTML = totalPlayers.reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b; }) + ' Total Players';
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to have changed anything. I have literally no idea about any of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you manage both web server use websocket this will enable the server to push the updated results back to client.

If server is out of your control,

a. Pull the results and append only the results (data) not entire html section.

b. Append only modified information not entire information

c. Use pagination or chunk if data you are loading is huge

d. Ensure the objects and listeners initiated or destroyed if you are creating new on every changes.

Thanks.